# Does adding an extra, non-entropic keyfile lower security?

Tags: encryption, truecrypt, entropy

Suppose I create two TrueCrypt volumes using keyfiles. The first volume uses a keyfile generated by TrueCrypt, whereas the second one uses the same keyfile in addition to a second, non-entropic keyfile (picture a file in which most of its bytes are 0s, but has a few ones with different values). Which of the two volumes would be more secure and harder to decrypt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be a bit confused about what "entropic" means. In the context of information security, "entropy" is a measure of the unknown. It is often expressed in bits, which is a logarithmic scale: "10 bits of entropy" means "could assume 2<sup>10</sup> possible values with uniform probability". Entropy translates to security in that an attacker, trying to guess a value with *n* bits of entropy through brute force will need, on average, *2<sup>n-1</sup>* tries. Beyond about 100 bits of entropy, brute force is infeasible because of the sheer cost (not enough energy is produced on Earth to complete that computation).

Being logarithmic, entropy adds up: if you concatenate a piece of data with 20 bits of entropy, next to a piece of data with 13 bits of entropy (and independent of the first piece), then the total entropy is 33 bits.

**By definition**, a "non-entropic file" is a file with 0 entropy, meaning that the attacker already knows it. Appending a non-entropic file will add exactly 0 to the entropy, so it won't make anything stronger.

When using "key files", [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/keyfiles) uses a [cryptographic hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) which has a nice property of "keeping entropy around" in a much more compact form. A hash function with a 160-bit output will necessarily reduce entropy to at most 160 bits, but the bright side is that it won't reduce it any further. And 160 bits is far more than enough to defeat brute force attacks. Therefore, adding a "non-entropic" key file will not *reduce* your effective security (but that's because TrueCrypt does things properly).